# How to index dynamic fields in Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

Trying to create text search for items. Item's `optionalFields` field may contain `[{name: 'tag', type: 'text', value: 'books'}]` and I may want to find item by item's tag value. It's working for `name` field but not for dynamic fields inside `optionalFields`.

```
const itemSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      index: true,
    },
author: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
optionalFields: {
      type: [
        {
          name: "String",
          type: "String",
          value: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
        },
      ],
    },
})

itemSchema.index({ name: "text" });
```

I tried

```
itemSchema.index({ name: "text", "optionalFields.value": "text" })
```